# Finding device heading with ARKit and ARGeoTrackingConfiguration

Tags: swift, gps, location, augmented-reality, arkit

I am working on an app where I need to orient a custom view depending on the device heading. I am using `ARKit` and `ARSCNView` with the `ARGeoTrackingConfiguration` in order to overlay my custom view in real world geographic coordinates. I've got a lot of it working, but the heading of my custom view is off.

Once the `ARSession` gets a `ARGeoTrackingStatus.State` of `.localized`, I need to be able to get the devices heading (0-360) so that I can orient my view. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this missing piece. Any help is appreciated.